# read `wav` file with `tf.audio.decode_wav`

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the tensorflow tutorial for audio recognition at [simple_audio](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio). The notebook works very well.

As a next step, I wanted to record my own voice and then run it through the model trained in tensorflow.
I first generated a recording:

```py
seconds=1
sr=16000
nchannels=1
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * sr), samplerate=sr, channels=nchannels)
sd.wait()
wavfile.write(filename, sr, myrecording)
```

So far so good, I can play my recording. But when I try to load the file with `tf.audio.decode_wav` similar to this:

```py
audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(filename)
audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Bad audio format for WAV: Expected 1 (PCM), but got3 [Op:DecodeWav]

Any pointers on what might be going wrong are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Would have written this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet)

The default encoding for WAV files is called "16 bit PCM", which means the recorded sound is represented using 16-bit int data before it is written to your WAV file.

`tf.audio.decode_wav()` states in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav): "Decode a 16-bit PCM WAV file to a float tensor". Thus passing a WAV file using any other encoding (24-bit encoding, in your case) would result in an error like the one you received.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it. It has to do with the bit representation. I was creating a file in `24-bit` while for some reason `tf.audio.decode_wav` only takes 16-bit files.

It is not clear to me why, but marking this as solved for now.

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `scipy.wavfile.write` function, which appears you are using, does not automatically save wav files in a 16 bits format. Hence, from the example in the [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html), you should do something like that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.wavfile import write

# your other code here
write(filename, sr, myrecording.astype(np.int16))
```