# "Bad audio format for WAV" when reading a wav file

Tags: tensorflow, wav, librosa, audio-processing

I have a set of wav files that I want to generate a spectrogram of. But when I use the tf.audio.decode_wav function, I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Bad audio format for WAV: Expected 1 (PCM), but
> got7 [Op:DecodeWav]

How do I circumvent this error? Are there any other ways to generate a log mel spectrogram for wav files using tensorflow?

I am aware of librosa package, but I would prefer tensorflow.

The code is:

```
def decode_audio(audio_binary):
  audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
  return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)

def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform
```

Comment: please provide code

Comment: Can you upload your file with error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read \`wav\` file with \`tf.audio.decode\_wav\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813162/read-wav-file-with-tf-audio-decode-wav)

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that your files indicate that they have samples encoded as 8-bit mulaw.

As described in the TensorFlow documentation for [tf.audio.decode_wav](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav), only 16-bit PCM WAV is supported by this method.

You would need to re-encode your wave files prior to passing them to tensorflow. Something like ffmpeg could help here.